# How to change img src in Model-Class?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

in my View I have an image and a dropdownlist:

```
<img id="img" src="~/images/flowers/red.png" height="32" width="32"/>
<select asp-for="Flower" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Flowers>() onchange="changeImagePath"></select>
```

I want to change the image when I change the item in the dropdownlist. I tried to write a methode in my Model-Class:

```
 public void changeImagePath (object sender, EventArgs e){
    img.src="~/images/flowers/blue.png";
}
```

but get the error, that img is not found.

I'm a beginner in asp.net core so I think I just forget something? I'm not sure that's how you do it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a javascript function like the one below

```
function changeImagePath(){
    $('#img').attr('src', '/images/flowers/blue.png');
}
```

just ensure that the image path is correct.

Comment: thanks, that works. just out of interest: Is there a way to do it without JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript is use to manupulate html dom, if you want to do it without any frontend script, then you have to do a full page post. that is to say you will reload the page for the image to change.

Comment: You can use partial view for the image, but it will need ajax call. Javascript at the end.

Comment: @Bosco so I would need something like a reload-methode in my controller?

Comment: @niz173 Yes that would return the path to the image you want to display. Actually JavaScript is the best because you can still use it to get the path of the image through the controller even if the path was stored in your database.